# Variable declared and not used in a loop

Tags: go

Got confusion with a function

```
package main

import "fmt"

func dominantIndex(nums []int) int {
    var max, max2 = -12423421, -12423421
    var i, j = -1, -1
    for k, num := range nums {
        if num > max {
            max, max2 = num, max
            i, j = k, i
        } else if num > max2 {
            max2 = num
            j = k
        }
    }
    if max >= max2*2 {
        return i
    }
    return -1
}


func main() {
    var a = []int{3, 6, 100, 1, 0 }
    fmt.Print(dominantIndex(a))
}
```

I have to insert a nonsense statement in the loop such as `j = j`. Otherwise, it raises `./hello.go:7:6: j declared and not used`. Wonder if there is any fix.

Comment: Fix: If you intended to use `j` in the program, then fix the program.  Otherwise, delete `j`.

Comment: Thanks - Cerise! My mistake. It solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign a value to j, but you don't use j. That is the problem. You could as well leave j out, without changing the functionality of the code.